# Javapns Communication exception:Connection refused to ConnectionToAppleServer

Tags: java, android, ios, tomcat, javapns

I use the `javapns2.2 jar` for push notification in iOS devices. The java source run in my local tomcat server delivers the push notification to my device. When i try with the live url the connection gets refused. Below is my tomcat live server log. I tried with the other members mentioned with firewall settings and nothing got me worked. I cannot detect the issue since it runs good in localhost but not in live server. Kindly suggest me to resolve.

**ServerLog**

> Pay load is {"aps":{"alert":"test message","sound":"default"}}
>   javapns.communication.exceptions.CommunicationException: Communication exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
>       at javapns.communication.ConnectionToAppleServer.getSSLSocket(ConnectionToAppleServer.java:158)
>       at javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager.initializeConnection(PushNotificationManager.java:106)
>       at javapns.Push.sendPayload(Push.java:171)
>       at javapns.Push.payload(Push.java:149)
>       at org.sabarish.model.PushMessage.sendNotification(PushMessage.java:111)
>       at com.sabarish.api.Push.sendPushNotification(Push.java:56)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:402)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:349)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:106)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:259)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:318)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1010)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:382)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:345)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:220)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:81)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
>       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
>       at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:618)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.(SSLSocketImpl.java:407)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:88)
>       at javapns.communication.ConnectionToAppleServer.getSSLSocket(ConnectionToAppleServer.java:155)
>       ... 49 more

Comment: Is your certification working properly? It seems like problem with your certification